# ADB not finding my Archos device

Tags: android, debugging, adb, tablet, archos

I have the Archos 80 Xenon tablet, and for some reason i can't locate it in the device picker on my eclipse.

I have downloaded the adb from archos's site, and updated my usb driver.

Still nothing showing up, i really need help.

Comment: trying adding it manually using hardware id

Answer (score 12):

if your device is not recognizable with adb you can use a manufacturer adb driver to fix the issue or add the device manually. Remember that, device software which help to recognize your device to windows and help you to transfer data is not the adb driver.

How to install a device manually?

**Step 1 [Get the Google USB Driver]**

from Android SDK manager install, Google USB driver from extras section.

**Step 2 [Find the Device Hardware ID]**

1. Go to your Windows device manager
2. find your device from the list
3. then go to its properties.
4. Select details tab.
5. Select Hardware ID from drop down.

You will see something like bellow.

```
USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE2&REV_0228&MI_00
USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE2&MI_00
```

Copy these two line.

**Step 3 [Update Your USB Driver]**

Go to your device installation folder
Under sdk\extras\google\usb_driver you will see a file `android_winsub.inf`
Open the file

Go to Section `[Google.NTx86]`
you will see something like bellow(Do not worry about exact match of device name. ).

```
;Google Nexus Q
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_2C10
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_2C11
```

Copy this and create a new entry just bellow with your device name. So new entry will look like this,

```
;My Nexus Q
    %SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, [Things you just copied on step 2]
    %SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, [Things you just copied on step 2]
```

do the same for section `[Google.NTamd64]`

**Step 4[Installation]**

1. Go to windows Device Manager
2. Your Device Properties
3. Driver-> update driver

Show your newly modified `android_winsub.inf` and install.

**Final Step**
restart you adb.

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This may cause by a plenty of reasons.
You might need to check the device support in Archos website. I've found the link(http://www.archos.com/support/support_tech/updates_adb.html?lang=en) for you. 

As far as I know, not every Android devices is ready for development out-of-box.
But the solutions are quite similar:
 1. Download the driver of your device and install it.
 2. Edit "%USERPROFILE%\.android\adb_usb.ini" file and wirte "0x0e79" to specify your device vendor ID
 3. After above, restart your adb server:
    cd "location of your platform-tools dir"
    adb kill-server
    adb start-server

Above is from my personal experience, please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong :)
```

Comment: I have tried all of this, i downloaded, updated my driver, added the vendor id and restarted the adb.

When i connect the device it says that it is plugged in and in debugging, but on the eclipse no device is shown

Comment: 1. Check Device Manager to see if the driver is properly installed (right click "My Computer" and select "properties"->"Hardware" Tab->"Device Manager"  2. Can you see the device in file explorer? 3. Make sure to enable USB debugging on your device.